# Oracle performance issue in getting first row in sub query

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g, subquery

I have a performance issue on the following (example) select statement that returns the first row using a sub query:

```
SELECT ITEM_NUMBER,
       PROJECT_NUMBER,       
       NVL((SELECT DISTINCT
                   FIRST_VALUE(L.LOCATION) OVER (ORDER BY L.SORT1, L.SORT2 DESC) LOCATION
            FROM   LOCATIONS L
            WHERE  L.ITEM_NUMBER=P.ITEM_NUMBER
                   AND L.PROJECT_NUMBER=P.PROJECT_NUMBER
           ),
          P.PROJECT_NUMBER) LOCATION
FROM   PROJECT P
```

The `DISTINCT` is causing the performance issue by performing a `SORT` and `UNIQUE` but I can't figure out an alternative.

I would however prefer something akin to the following but referencing within 2 select statements doesn't work:

```
SELECT ITEM_NUMBER,
       PROJECT_NUMBER,       
       NVL((SELECT LOCATION
            FROM   (SELECT L.LOCATION LOCATION
                           ROWNUM RN
                    FROM   LOCATIONS L
                    WHERE  L.ITEM_NUMBER=P.ITEM_NUMBER
                           AND L.PROJECT_NUMBER=P.PROJECT_NUMBER
                    ORDER BY L.SORT1, L.SORT2 DESC
                   ) R
            WHERE RN <=1
           ), P.PROJECT_NUMBER) LOCATION
FROM   PROJECT P
```

Additionally:
 - My permissions do not allow me to create a function.
 - I am cycling through 10k to 100k records in the main query.
 - The sub query could return 3 to 7 rows before limiting to 1 row.

Any assistance in improving the performance is appreciated.

Comment: Use ROW_NUMBER instead of FIRST_VALUE

Comment: How do you know the DISTINCT is the cause of your performance issue? Just because you see a SORT / UNIQUE in your explain plan doesn't imply that your query is actually sorting, or sorting a lot of data, let alone getting a performance hit for it. Post your explain plan.

Comment: @JeffreyKemp, +1 you raise good points. I know there is no direct link (and don't want a debate) between the **EXPLAIN PLAN** and **PERFORMANCE** but the amount of extra work involved in getting the solution my way, I'm sure I've missed a simple solution. I can only go be the **EXPLAIN** to estimate the work the system is doing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's difficult to understand without sample data and cardinalities, but does this get you what you want? A unique list of projects and items, with the first occurrence of a location?

```
SELECT 
P.ITEM_NUMBER,
P.PROJECT_NUMBER,       
MIN(L.LOCATION) KEEP (DENSE_RANK FIRST ORDER BY L.SORT1, L.SORT2 DESC) LOCATION
FROM   
LOCATIONS L
INNER JOIN
PROJECT P
ON L.ITEM_NUMBER=P.ITEM_NUMBER
AND L.PROJECT_NUMBER=P.PROJECT_NUMBER
GROUP BY
P.ITEM_NUMBER,
P.PROJECT_NUMBER
```

Comment: Yes you are right that is the output I need. I think your solution works well, certainty a lot simpler than mine. I'll reply tommorrow with an outcome.

Comment: You're missing the NVL but otherwise yes; this is what I would have answered; it saves the inline sub-query (which isn't _always_ evil for those reading this) but more importantly it should be a lot more efficient.

Comment: Thanks my query went from in excess of 2 minutes down to 6 seconds!

Comment: Excellent. Those analytical functions are magic. Well not magic but oftentimes the closest thing to a silver bullet solution.

Answer (score -2):

I encounter similar problem in the past -- and while this is not ultimate solution (in fact might just be a corner-cuts) -- Oracle query optimizer can be adjusted with the OPTIMIZER_MODE init param.

Have a look at chapter 11.2.1 on http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28274/optimops.htm#i38318

> FIRST_ROWS
>
> The optimizer uses a mix of cost and heuristics to find a best plan
>   for fast delivery of the first few rows. Note: Using heuristics
>   sometimes leads the query optimizer to generate a plan with a cost
>   that is significantly larger than the cost of a plan without applying
>   the heuristic. FIRST_ROWS is available for backward compatibility and
>   plan stability; use FIRST_ROWS_n instead.

Of course there are tons other factors you should analyse like your index, join efficiency, query plan etc..

Comment: -1 FIRST_ROWS is an optimizer hint. The OP is asking about a subquery which is supposed to return the first row - i.e. *only the first row* - I know it's confusing, but the two things are very different and have different purposes.